# What happens to equal items in javascript sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to know what does the Javascript sort function does with equal items (e.g. in what order are the equal items sorted?)

Example: if I have an array of object, each of which has the following structure

```
{
    name:string,
    type:string
}
```

I want to use the sort function to sort the above array so that the list is:

1. firstly sorted by type in ascending order (a specific sorting function is provided)
2. items with same type will be sorted by name in ascending order

Example:

before sorting:

```
[{name:"John", type:"type3"},{name:"Tim", type:"type2"},{name:"Buck", type: "type2"},{name:"Emma", type:"type2"}]
```

after sorting:

```
[{name:"Buck", type:"type2"},{name:"Emma", type:"type2"},{name:"Tim", type:"type2"},{name:"John", type:"type3"}]
```

The solution I came up with that **seemed** to work (based on the particular result) is:

1. sort the whole list by name (because sort function uses an in-place algorithm, the original list will be sorted by name after this)
2. sort the whole list by type

This means the sort function **seemed** to keep the original order of the items that are equal (e.g. the second sort places the items with the same "type2" in the original order, which is the order of the list sorted by name)

But I cannot find documents to back this theory of mine up.

My question is: Is this behavior (where the sort function retains the original order for equal items) true for all cases and across different browsers?

I would appreciate any documents that confirm this behavior.

Comment: When a sorting function keeps original ordering of elements with equal sort keys, the function is said to be **stable**. JavaScript does **not** require `Array.prototype.sort()` to be stable, and typical sorting algorithms like quicksort are not stable.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I appreciate the concept of the "stable sorting algorithm". Your answer is very spot on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort by two keys, you only need one pass through `.sort()`. In the comparison function, you only need to compare the secondary key when the primary keys are the same:

```
yourArray.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  var c = o1.type.localeCompare(o2.type);
  if (c) return c;
  return o1.name.localeCompare(o2.name);
});
```

If the comparison (via `.localeCompare()`) of the types returns 1 or -1, then that is returned to be used to order the objects. If the types are equal, the comparison moves on to the names.